# How do I print one or multiple objects from an ArrayList with a particular attribute?

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, arraylist

I have a Book class:

```
public class Book {
    public String title;
  
    public  String author;

    public  int genre;
    
    public Book(){}
  
    public Book(String title, String author, int genre) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.genre = genre;
    }
  

    public String getBookTitle() {
        return  title;
    }
    
    public String getBookAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    
    public String getBookGenre() {
        if (genre == 1) {
          return ("Fantasy");
        }
        else if (genre == 2) {
          return ("Science Fiction");
        }
        else if (genre == 3) {
          return ("Dystopian");
        }
        return "genre";
        
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("Title: " + this.getBookTitle() + " \nAuthor: " + this.getBookAuthor() + " \nGenre: " + this.getBookGenre() + "\n");
    }
    
}
```

And I have a LibraryDatabase class that has an ArrayList of two Book objects:

```
import java.util.*;
public class LibraryDatabase extends Book {
  List<Book> bookDatabase = new ArrayList<>();

  public LibraryDatabase() {
      super();
  }

  public List<Book> books() {
    Book book1 = new Book("Harry Potter", "J.K. Rowling", 1);
    Book book2 = new Book("Neuromancer", "William Gibson", 2);

    bookDatabase.add(book1);
    bookDatabase.add(book2);
    return bookDatabase;
  }
}
```

I want to allow the user to choose which genre they would like and have the console print out all objects that have that genre as an attribute.
I have this method in a separate class:

```
public void showTitles() {
    LibraryDatabase libraryDatabase = new LibraryDatabase();
    Scanner kbMeter = new Scanner(System.in);
    String genre = kbMeter.nextLine();
    if (genre.equals(libraryDatabase.getBookGenre())) {
      //???
    }

  }
```

I don't know what to put inside the if statement in order to print out all objects with that genre. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `for` loop that goes through each `Book` in the database should work:

```java
for (Book book : bookDatabase) {
    if (book.getBookGenre().equals(genre) {
        System.out.println(book);
    }
}
```

Comment: bookDatabase can't be found as a symbol when I run this.

Comment: @FouadSaffar Well, you never specified where `showTitles` was, so I assumed it was in your `LibraryDatabase` class. That's probably why that error is showing. I think what you want to do is replace `bookDatabase` with `libraryDatabase.books()`. Try that and see if it works

Comment: @megargayu calling `books()` may not be best idea since `showTitles` will probably be called many times but each `books()` call adds two books to `bookDatabase` list. It's code should probably be moved to `LibraryDatabase` constructor and instead of `books()` there *can* be method like `public List<Book> getAllBooks(){return new ArrayList<>(bookDatabase); }` to return copy of list of all books (to prevent modifying original `bookDatabase`).

Comment: @Pshemo true, I didn't really think of all those complications. in reality you probably would want to completely refactor how this code works, as `LibraryDatabase` shouldn't extend `Book`, `showTitles` probably shouldn't ask for input from the user and instead get it as parameters, and then a seperate class be added to call the function, etc. Also, it would be much better to use a `HashMap<String, Book> genres` variable for O(1) lookup

Answer (score 0):

I suggest at least refactor `books()` method like this to prevent reference escape

```
public Collection<Book> getBooks() {
    Book book1 = new Book("Harry Potter", "J.K. Rowling", 1);
    Book book2 = new Book("Neuromancer", "William Gibson", 2);

    bookDatabase.add(book1);
    bookDatabase.add(book2);
    return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(bookDatabase);
}
```

and refactor `showTitles` method to make it use java 8 features and more general:

```
public void showTitles(Consumer<Book> consumer) {
    LibraryDatabase libraryDatabase = new LibraryDatabase();
    Scanner kbMeter = new Scanner(System.in);
    String genre = kbMeter.nextLine();
    libraryDatabase.getBooks()
                .stream()
                .filter(b -> b.getBookGenre().equals(genre))
                .forEach(consumer);

}
```

and use this API like this:

```
LibraryDatabase db = new LibraryDatabase();
db.showTitles(b -> System.out.println(String.format("%s, %s, %s", b.getBookAuthor(), b.getBookTitle(), b.getBookGenre())));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "use this API like this." I'm new to computer science and I don't exactly know which part of my code the API is.

Comment: Also, where did Consumer come from?

Comment: by API I mean `showTitles` method. you can pass a consumer to your method to do your desired logic for each book. here I only print them, you can provide another consumer to do other thing when you invoke this method

Answer (score 0):

There is something fundamentally wrong with your design. Your `LibraryDatabase` shouldn't extend `Book`.

You can either expose a `findBookByGenre(String genre)` method in your `LibraryDatabase` class or filter the list returned by `books()`.

```
        libraryDatabase.books().forEach(book -> {
            if ("aaa".equals(book.getBookGenre())) {
                System.out.println(book.getBookTitle());
            }
        });
```